# Android parse address to URL without a protocl

Tags: java, android

I'm after a clean way of parsing an address like "www.google.com" into a URL object that assumes the http protocol if no protocol is given (but will still work correctly for "https://www.google.com").

The java.net.URL constructor correctly spits out these addresses as malformed URLs, and I can't find a built-in method to do it.

Zero internet-points are available for suggesting I search for "://" or similar. I need a clean way of doing this that properly parses the address.

Comment: Please feel free to explain a "clean way" for parsing that does not involve parsing, since you have stated that you do not want your parsing to actually do parsing. After all, [the IETF RFC for URI syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) specifically calls out `://` as being a relevant construct (see "URI Syntactic Components"). How are you planning on parsing *any* URL if the parsing algorithm cannot follow the spec?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sure thing. A clean way to do solve this problem involves me not writing my own parser or searching through the string for '://'. Android already has reliable parsers, I just need to know the right API calls to use. I'm happy to use a parser, I'm not happy to hack together something unreliable by searching the string.

Comment: "Android already has reliable parsers, I just need to know the right API calls to use" -- there aren't any, AFAIK. It is possible there's some third-party code snippet or library you can use, which is why I retagged this to `java`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with the following, at least until presented with a test case that doesn't work:

```
URL url=null;

try {
  url=new URL(yourString);
}
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  url=new URL("http://"+yourString);
}
```

Basically, retry the proposed URL with an `http://` prefix, and if that parses, assume that it's the no-scheme scenario.

Comment: What if the URL is with https?

Comment: @AlexArvanitidis: You are welcome to create a more elaborate fallback mechanism (e.g., try the original URL, then try it with `https://`, then try it with `http://`).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
String url = ...
            if (!url.startsWith("https://") && !url.startsWith("http://")){
            url = "http://" + url;
        }
```

Comment: Not really. There are a whole lot more schemes out there beyond http and https, which this method doesn't account for. It also doesn't handle the case of the url string starting with a space. I'm after something that's more robust than this.

Comment: @Hbcdev: "There are a whole lot more schemes out there beyond http and https, which this method doesn't account for" -- however, there are a finite and countable number of schemes that will be relevant. After all, `java.net.URL` only handles five, and you seemed comfortable with using that.